# What's the probability of throwing 4 out of 4 times an '8' , with 8-sided dice?

Tags: probability, dice

Someone throws $4$ $8$-sided dice and all of them land on $8$.  What's the probability of this event?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order for users to help you find a solution to this question, please provide some context. What approaches have you tried? Showing your dead ends will help users guide your thought processes. It also gives us an idea of your mathematical knowledge so we can address your question at a level that is appropriate for you.

Comment: We should assume that the dice are fair and use standard numbering (*which in particular implies each die is equally likely to be any of the results and are independent of one another*).  If you were to throw just one die, it would be $\frac{1}{8}$ chance of rolling an eight.  Similarly so for the second die.  For the first die to be an eight *and* the second die to be an eight, as these are independent events (*as per our assumption that the dice are fair*) we simply multiply these probabilities together to get $\frac{1}{8^2}$.  Do this twice more to account for the third and fourth dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming fair die the probability of ruling an $8$ in one roll is the number of ways you can roll on $8$  (Either you do or you don't so that is $1$ way) divided by the number of ways you can roll anything.  (There are eight things you can roll, so there are $8$ ways you can roll a die.)

If you do an event a multiple number of times and the result of doing it once has no bearing on the probability of doing it again (as is the case with rolling a die--- whatever you roll the first time will have no bearing what will happen the second time) the the probability of event A and also event B will be the probability of event A multiplied by the probability of event B.

So the probability of doing a single event $k$ times in a row, will be the probability of doing it once multiplied by itself $k$ times.

And that should give you *ALL* the information you need to figure this out.